# IRC client that lets you group related channels

Tags: linux, irc

I need an IRC client for linux that would let me group related channels in the channel switcher treebar. For instance, if I were connected to a network called `IRCNetwork`, it should look something like this:

```
IRCNetwork
- Topic 1
    - channel 1
    - channel 2
    - ...
- Topic 2
    - channel 3
    - channel 4
    - ...
```

from what I've been able to see, all IRC clients have channel switcher treebars structured in the following fashion:

```
IRCNetwork
- channel 1
- channel 2
- channel 3
- channel 4
- ...
```

... none of them lets you create 'subnodes'. Since I autojoin a lot of channels this is very important to me and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.